# Is there a sequence ($X_n$) of random variables s.t. $\mathbb{E}(\liminf X_n) = 0$ and $\liminf \mathbb{E}(X_n) = 1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, limsup-and-liminf

I have been working a lot on the following questions: find a sequence ($X_n$) of random variables such that $\mathbb{E}(\liminf X_n) = 0$ and $\liminf \mathbb{E}(X_n) = \infty$?

I think that the desired sequence should be such that $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $X_n(\omega) = 0 \; \forall n\geq k$, while at the same time $\exists k' \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{E}[X_n(\omega)] = \infty \; \forall n\geq k'$, (but I am not sure whether I must pick $k \neq k'$ in order not to lose generality).

To find this example, I thought about defining a sequence of random variables $Y_m$ such that each of them is bounded, i.e. $\mid Y_m\mid < c_m$, with $c_m$ strictly increasing in $m$. The random variable $X_n = Y_1 + Y_2 + ... + Y_n$, so that it is the sum of the first $n$ variables $Y$'s, for each $n$. However, I get stuck when I try to formalize this. Is this the right way to provide the example I am looking for?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example: On the unit interval define $X_n$ to be a box of height $h_n$ over the interval $(0,\frac1n]$, zero otherwise. It's clear that $X_n$ tends to zero pointwise since the boxes are getting narrower and squeezing toward the origin. Therefore $\liminf X_n=0$. Meanwhile, under Lebesgue measure, the area of the $n$th box is $E(X_n)=h_n/n$. You can choose $h_n$ so that $E(X_n)$ meets any desired requirement.

Comment: Thanks! I do not exactly get what you mean by "box": shouldn't $X_n(A)$ be equal to a real number, for each $A \in \mathcal{F}(\Omega$, which here coincides with $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$?

Comment: @Elle I mean $X_n$ has (constant) value $h_n$ on $(0,\frac1n]$ and is zero otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for keep bothering you, but could $h_n = \frac{n}{F(\frac{1}{n})}$ lead to the desired result, where $F(\cdot)$ denotes the cumulative distribution function.

Comment: @Elle You don't need $h_n$ to be very tricky. For example $h_n=n^2$ gives $E(X_n)=n$, which tends to infinity.

Comment: How can I formally establish that $X_n$ converges pointwise to a constant $0$ given the fact that $n^2 \to \infty$? I know that the interval over which $X_n$ is different from $0$ goes to $0$ as $n$ grows, but in the limit don't I get something like $\frac{\infty}{0}$? I understand that my questions are quite stupid, by excuse is that I am completely new to the field and I am studying it independently!

Comment: @Elle Given fixed $\omega\in[0,1]$, your aim is to prove the sequence of real numbers $\{X_n(\omega)\}$ tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. Argue that there exists $N$ such that $X_n(\omega)=0$ for all $n\ge N$; this proves pointwise convergence to zero. It helps to write out the sequence $X_n(\omega)$ for a typical $\omega$, say $\omega=0.04$, and study the behavior of the sequence as $n$ increases.